# error: Index out of range in segment control

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

While using segment control to populate the respective list under different segments, issues I am facing are as below

1. When the segment control is loaded in the tableview , the first segment is working fine and when I switch second segment it do populate the list but it gives error of **Index Out Of Range** when the list scrolled
2. The second segment control should load the different list as per the filter, but it loads the same list as the first segment control

I am using Swift IOS and Firestore Database for this
Below is the code I am sharing

```
class FirstSegementViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var segmentControl:UISegmentedControl!

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    var firstDetails:[FirstDetails] = []
    var secondDetails:[SecondDetails] = []

    var postKey:String = ""



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        retrieveAllPosts()
    }


    func retrieveAllPosts(){
        let postsRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("posts").whereField("post_author_id", isEqualTo: Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
            ).whereField("status", isEqualTo: false).limit(to: 50)

        postsRef.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in

            if let error = error {

                print(error.localizedDescription)

            } else {

                if let snapshot = snapshot {

                    for document in snapshot.documents {


                        let data = document.data()
                        //self.postKey = document.documentID
                        let username = data["post_author_username"] as? String ?? ""
                        let postTitle = data["postTitle"] as? String ?? ""
                        let postcategory = data["postcategory"] as? String ?? ""
                        let postContent = data["postContent"] as? String ?? ""
                        let postAuthorProfilePicUrl = data["post_user_profile_pic_url"] as? String ?? ""
                        let postAuthorSpinnerC = data["post_author_spinnerC"] as? String


                        let newSourse = FirstDetails(_documentId: document.documentID, _username: username, _postTitle: postTitle, _postcategory: postcategory, _postContent: postContent, _postuserprofileImagUrl: postAuthorProfilePicUrl, _postAuthorSpinncerC: postAuthorSpinnerC)



                        self.firstDetails.append(newSourse)
                        // print(self.postKey)
                    }
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }



    func retrieveAllPosts2(){
        let postsRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("posts").whereField("post_author_id", isEqualTo: Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).whereField("status", isEqualTo: true).limit(to: 50)
        postsRef.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in

            if let error = error {

                print(error.localizedDescription)

            } else {

                if let snapshot = snapshot {

                    for document in snapshot.documents {


                        let data = document.data()
                        //self.postKey = document.documentID
                        let username = data["post_author_username"] as? String ?? ""
                        let postTitle = data["postTitle"] as? String ?? ""
                        let postcategory = data["postcategory"] as? String ?? ""
                        let postContent = data["postContent"] as? String ?? ""
                        let postAuthorProfilePicUrl = data["post_user_profile_pic_url"] as? String ?? ""
                        let postAuthorSpinnerC = data["post_author_spinnerC"] as? String


                        let newSourse1 = SecondDetails(_documentId: document.documentID, _username: username, _postTitle: postTitle, _postcategory: postcategory, _postContent: postContent, _postuserprofileImagUrl: postAuthorProfilePicUrl, _postAuthorSpinncerC: postAuthorSpinnerC)


                        self.secondDetails.append(newSourse1)

                    }
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }



    @IBAction func indexChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
          switch segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex
         {
         case 0:
            retrieveAllPosts()
         // label1.text = "First Segment Selected"
         case 1:

            retrieveAllPosts2()
         // label1.text = "Second Segment Selected"
         default:
         break
         }

        //self.tableView.reloadData()
    }



    @objc func toComments(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        let commentbutton = sender as! UIButton
        let post = firstDetails[commentbutton.tag]
        postKey = post._documentId // or what key value it is
        print("hello")
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "toCommentsListforMWs", sender: self)

    }


     // MARK: - Navigation

     // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
     override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
     // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

        var vc = segue.destination as! CommentListViewController
        vc.postId = postKey

     }




    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}


extension FirstSegementViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        var value = 0
        switch segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex{
        case 0:
            value = firstDetails.count
            break
        case 1:
            value = secondDetails.count
            break
        default:
            break
        }
        return value
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as! MyWsPostCell
        switch segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex{
        case 0:
            cell.firstdetails1 = firstDetails[indexPath.row]
            cell.commentbutton.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.commentbutton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toComments(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

            break
        case 1:
            cell.completed1 = secondDetails[indexPath.row]

            cell.commentbutton.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.commentbutton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toComments(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

            break

        default:
            break
        }
        return cell
    }



}
```

Comment: When you fetch data from Firebase, I see you self.secondDetails.append(newSourse1), this will keep adding data to the list without removing previous one. This will make your table view show same set of data many times when you switch between tab 0 and 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `indexChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl)` function like this:

```
@IBAction func indexChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
      switch segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex
     {
         case 0:
            self.firstDetails.removeAll()
            retrieveAllPosts()
         // label1.text = "First Segment Selected"
         case 1:
            self.secondDetails.removeAll()
            retrieveAllPosts2()
         // label1.text = "Second Segment Selected"
         default:
         break
     }

    //self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your retrieveAllPosts() and retrieveAllPosts2() you need to empty the data you have already stored in the firstDetails and secondDetails array. Currently you are just appending the data everytime user changes the segment index.

```
func retrieveAllPosts() { 
self.firstDetails = [] 
//all of your code here
}

func retrieveAllPosts2() { 
self.secondDetails = [] 
//all of your code here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Before your Api hit, or before adding data to array remove the previous data in the array.

```
@IBAction func indexChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
      switch segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex
     {
     case 0:
        self.firstDetails.removeAll()// Remove data in array before u call Api

        retrieveAllPosts()
     case 1:
        self.secondDetails.removeAll()// Remove data in array before u call Api


        retrieveAllPosts2()
     default:
     break
     }

}
```

Comment: This answer is no different than @Musaddique's answer.